# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel but works from browser/POSTMAN

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https

I am kind of at a lost here.  Adding the ServicePointManager stuff usually fixes this but this time I keep getting the error below.  My server can access the same URL from the browser and POSTMAN.  But running this through the website fails.  This works on my local computer though.  I have TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 enabled on the server.

Is there anything wrong with my server TLS setup? https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=basketball.exposureevents.com

I am using CertifyTheWeb certificates, basically free SSL.  Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

I am sending to the link below which is rejecting the request when made from the code below from IIS.

https://www.nationalsportsid.com/tournament/6028

> Message :The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure
>   channel. Source :System Stack Trace :   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.nationalsportsid.com/tournament/" + nationalSportsId);
try
{
    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Logger.Error(ex);
}
```

**Here is what Message Analyzer records**

**Handshake**

[image]

**Alert**

[image]

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the http headers in w working and non work environment.  Most solution require adding a missing header to the request.  The error could be caused by different browsers installed on the PC and the wrong default browse settings are being used.

Comment: Which OS is on the machine making the request?

Comment: Windows 2012 R2

Comment: Can you assign the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` and make it return true and see if that helps? This would narrow down your problem.

Comment: I did that also, still did the same thing

Comment: What version of the .Net Framework are you using?

Comment: 4.7.1 is my version of .NET

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls advices to not set the SecurityProtocol property when using .NET >= 4.7. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I didn’t have a security protocol being set initially

Comment: On the server, in *Control Panel\Network and Internet\Internet Options* have you got *Use TLS 1.2* checked?

Comment: Any difference if you change this to simply be: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Are you using self-signed SSL cert?

Comment: No I am using LetsEcrypt free certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a configuration issue on the other server in Apache.  They loosened their SSL configuration, which I am not sure what they did but their previous configuration is below.  I can now make a HTTP request to their server.

```
SSLEngine on

# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE$
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your destination server does not have any of the cipher suites configured for SSLv2 and SSLv3. You need to check that your client allows connecting using the cipher suits configured on the server for the allowed SSL protocols.

In Windows use:

```
Get-TlsCipherSuite    [[-Name] <String>]    [<CommonParameters>]
```

in power shell. Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/get-tlsciphersuite

To add cipher suites in windows:

```
Enable-TlsCipherSuite
      [[-Position] <UInt32>]
      [-Name] <String>
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/Enable-TlsCipherSuite

To get the existing cipher suites in Linux:

```
openssl ciphers [-v] [-V] [-ssl2] [-ssl3] [-tls1] [cipherlist]
```

Reference - https://linux.die.net/man/1/ciphers

Comment: Ive asked for what they had before and what they switched too so I can do a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to connect first using *openssl* (either linux box or cygwin).

Your first step cold be something like this

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.nationalsportsid.com:443 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.nationalsportsid.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=www.nationalsportsid.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGTDCCBTSgAwIBAgISBIrqOzNTV7HxnH4SauB/Zeq2MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
MEoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MSMwIQYDVQQD
...
```

Please check this [how to connect to https protocol using openssl](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html). You could play around using different arguments.